# Python Threading Index Error (out of range)

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to run multiple threads with tweepy but it gives me every (Index Error list is out of range) How do I fix this?

```js
i = 0
numthreads = str(len(handles))


def worker():
  apimethod.run(chosenhandle = str(handles[i]))
  chosenhandle = str(handles[i])


while i <= len(handles) - 1:
  t = Thread(target = worker)
  t.start()
  i = i + 1
```

Comment: it looks like handles[i] in worker is not known to the worker. maybe use the args parameter in Thread ?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: Does it need to be a `while` loop there? Could you use a for loop instead so you don't have to mess around with an `i` variable as much?